# Kohana 3 validation rule error - Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I am trying to validate file, but I get following error: Illegal offset type in isset or empty  . What I am doing wrong ?

```
$array = Validate::factory($_FILES);
             $array->rule($_FILES['image'], 'Upload::not_empty');

             if ($array->check())
             {
               $directory = DOCROOT.'uploads/';
               $filepath = Upload::save($_FILES['image'], 'SDFFasreixcsd.jpg', $directory);
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Use `Validation` not `Validate`
2. Pass the file name as first argument

```
$validation = Validation::factory($_FILES)->rule('image', 'Upload::not_empty');  
if ($validation->check())  
{  
       // Your code  
}
```

Comment: Hi matino, thanks for reply. When I use validation instead of validate I get error Class 'Validation' not found. I think it is because I am using version 3.0.11 ? So how I can make it work with this version ?

Comment: No worries I sorted it out, by using code at the bottom. http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=validation.

Comment: @Johsas: looks like matino (partially) helped you out here, please consider upvoting or accepting. Thanks!